# Question about K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bigdata, cross-validation

In a machine learning procedure, suppose we've chosen k=10 for the "K-Fold Cross Validation".
After we do the k steps of "K-Fold Cross Validation", how do we choose the final model for the classifier ? (The one will we use in order to predict new data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K-Fold Cross validation confusion?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19140/k-fold-cross-validation-confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-fold cross validation only helps you giving an estimation of the error you are going to make with a given model. K-fold can be used in order to tune hyperparameters: we have a model that depends on some hyperparameters, we compute the K-fold validation error using different values of the hyperparameters, and we take the model with the lowest cross-validation error. Finally, we train the model with the chosen hyperparameters with all the training data and we build a classifier based on that model.